# Is paypal do direct payment possible from individual account

Tags: php, paypal

I have PayPal Individual account and I want my customers can pay via credit and debit card. For that I am using paypal dodirect payment method. In that we need API signature, username and password.

I have tried taking credentials from my paypal account > selling tools > API access > Add or edit API permissions but nothing happens with this. It just redirects to setting page (https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/settings/)

My question is, can I get API access signature, username and password for do direct payment from my individual account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by individual you mean a Personal PayPal account, then no, you won't be able to do that.  You'll need a business account for access to most APIs, and you'll need PayPal Payments Pro for access to DoDirectPayment specifically.

PayPal Pro is $30/mo, however, I can get you a Pro account for free if you want to [contact me directly](https://www.angelleye.com/contact-us/) to discuss.

Comment: Thanks for clarification